# How to require a property using Json.NET.Schema?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I am trying to create a schema to ensure that outside-supplied JSON is of the following form:

```
{ Username: "Aaron" }
```

Right now, I'm creating a Newtonsoft JSchema object in C# by doing:

```
var sch = new JSchema()
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    AllowAdditionalProperties = false,
    Properties =
    {
        {
            "Username",
            new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.String }
        }
    }
};
```

This is close, but does not require the presence of the Username property. I've tried the following:

```
var sch = new JSchema()
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    AllowAdditionalProperties = false,
    Properties =
    {
        {
            "Username",
            new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.String }
        }
    },
    Required = new List<string> { "Username" }
};
```

But I get:

```
Error CS0200 Property or indexer 'JSchema.Required' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

And indeed, the documentation notes that the Required property is read-only:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema_Required.htm

Am I missing something? Why would the Required property be read-only? How can I require the presence of Username?

Comment: Does the `JSchema` have any overloaded constructors?

Comment: Or you could try to use the `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attribute over the properties you want to be required

Comment: You can use C# List Initialization syntax with read-only list properties by doing `Required = { "UserName" }`. The C# compiler will change it to `Required.Add("UserName")` behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set `Required` (is only a `get`) use instead this:

```
var sch = new JSchema()
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    AllowAdditionalProperties = false,
    Properties =
    {
        {
            "Username",
            new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.String }
        }
    },
};
sch.Required.Add("Username");
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @PinBack from 2017 is incorrect: you *can* use [C# Collection Initialization syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) with read-only list properties, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431659/object-initializer-for-readonly-properties-in-c-sharp):

```
var sch = new JSchema()
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    AllowAdditionalProperties = false,
    Properties =
    {
        {
            "Username",
            new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.String }
        }
    },
    Required = // <-- here!
    {
        "Username"
    }
};
```