# Object initializer for readonly properties in c#

Tags: c#, projection, readonly, object-initializers

If you have the class:

```
class Foo {
      Bar Bar { get; } = new Bar();
}

class Bar {
      string Prop {get; set; }
}
```

You can use a object initialise like:

```
var foo = new Foo { 
    Bar = { Prop = "Hello World!" }
}
```

If you have a class

```
class Foo2 {
      ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; } = new List<Bar>();
}
```

You can write

```
var foo = new Foo2 { 
    Bars = { 
        new Bar { Prop = "Hello" }, 
        new Bar { Prop = "World" }
    }
}
```

but, I would like to write something like

```
var items = new [] {"Hello", "World"};
var foo = new Foo2 { 
    Bars = { items.Select(s => new Bar { Prop = s }) }
}
```

However, the code above does not compile with:

> cannot assigne IEnumerable to Bar

I cannot write:

```
var foo = new Foo2 { 
    Bars = items.Select(s => new Bar { Prop = s })
}
```

Property Bars is readonly.

Can this be archived?

Comment: @Hans Passant: That will give List<Bar> cannot be assigned to Bar

Comment: You'll have to go the long way and call `Bars.Add` for each individual item, if all you have is `ICollection`. Object initializers are only syntactic shorthand; C# is generally wary of adding syntax that adds runtime overhead under the covers and prefers that you be explicit about it (there are exceptions to this, of course).

Comment: @Flater Seems correct to me. Which one do you think is wrong?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza No, it is read-only.

Comment: @Flater, Bars does not have a setter, so it is read-only right?

Comment: Too much syntax sugar causes language decay.  Foo2 needs a constructor so you can initialize Bars.

Comment: This might also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666937/2946329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the *actual* compiler errors ([and the docs for collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)), you'll find that collection initializers are merly syntactic sugar for `Add()` calls:

> CS1950: The best overloaded collection initalizer method `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Bar>.Add(Bar)` has some invalid arguments
>
> CS1503: Argument `#1` cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Bar>` expression to type `Bar`

So the syntax `SomeCollection = { someItem }` will be compiled to `SomeCollection.Add(someItem)`. And you can't add `IEnumerable<Bar>` to a collection of `Bar`s.

You need to manually add all items:

```
foreach (bar in items.Select(s => new Bar { Prop = s }))
{
    foo.Bars.Add(bar);
}
```

Or, given shorter code is your goal, do the same in `Foo2`'s constructor:

```
public class Foo2 
{
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; }
    
    public Foo2() : this(Enumerable.Empty<Bar>()) { }
    
    public Foo2(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>(bars);
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize Foo2 like this:

```
var foo = new Foo2(items.Select(...));
```

For a funny abuse of the collection initializer syntax as supposed by @JeroenMostert, you could use an extension method:

```
public static class ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ICollection<string> Bar { get; } = new List<string>();
}

var foo = new Foo
{
    Bar = { new [] { "foo", "bar", "baz" } }
};
```

But that's just nasty.

Comment: Well, that "overloaded call" error does give us an interesting way to do this: `Bars = { items.Select(s => new Bar { Prop = s }) }` will be accepted if we write an `public static void Add<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)` extension method. I wouldn't be a fan of this (how easy is it to get confused by leaving out the braces -- and what happens if we have a collection of collections?), but it's something.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would love to turn that so cool comment into an answer, but how...? Can we make up a question together? Maybe talk somewhere in chat?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: as I see it, that remark could just be folded into one of the answers on this question. I wouldn't make it an answer myself since, as I mentioned, I don't really want to see this in production code (although, thinking about it, I may actually have used a variation on this myself somewhere -- bad me). I don't care a blot about attribution, so feel free to steal it if you're so inclined.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 2):

`Bars = { ... }` Doesn't do an assignment. Instead it calls `Add` for every item in the initializer. That is why it doesn't work.

That is why `Bars = items.Select(s => new Bar { Prop = s })` gives the same error: it is an assignment, not a list to add.

There is no option other that using a constructor to pass in the values, or use regular `Add` or `AddRange` statements after the constructor has ran.

Comment: Well no, The second one would work if Bars would not be read-only. It fails because it is read-only. I want is to Add every item in the selector.

Comment: That is what I said in other words. Since it is an assignment, the property can't be read-only. So don't assign but call `Add` instead.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: that's a regular object initializer, not a collection initializer. The syntax `Bar = { Prop = ... }` is different from `Bar = { Prop }`, despite the superficial resemblance. Whether or not `Bar` is readonly doesn't matter for the object initializer, as long as `Prop` is writable -- it doesn't assign a new `Bar`. This is documented in the [draft specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#object-initializers), so it should go all the way back to C# 6.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: `{ Bar = new Bar { Prop = ... } }` is an object initializer that initializes the property `Bar` with a newly allocated `Bar` object of which the `Prop` field or property is initialized. This will fail if `Bar` is read-only (in all language versions). `{ Bar = { Prop = ... } }` is a nested object initializer that will initialize the `Prop` field or property of `Bar`, which will work even if `Bar` is read-only. They're both object initializers (albeit with different semantics), not collection initializers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert TIL nested object initializer. Thank you for your patience.